# Allow users to access sharepoint list directly

Tags: list

Is it feasible to allow users to access the list in the backend directly?

I have created a list and set its permission for specific users. I want to allow users to access this list cause all they want to do is add/edit/view/delete records which is provided in sharepoint lists by default.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `Backend`? You do not want to show that list in Left Navigation and wants user to go from site contents and access the list for basic operation?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what kind of rights do you want to give it to the user, if you give full control right to the user he can access the backend of the list. And if you want to give the add/update/delete/read permissions to the user then you can give him contribute rights. You can make dataview or xsltlistview web parts and can use sharepoint add, edit & display forms customize them using sharepoint designer. And view the list to user through dataview, xsltlistview webparts, datatables or jqgrid by putting them on site pages.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I mean is it a good practice giving the user contribution permission on that particular list. So when the user wants to add/edit/view/delete a record, he/she accesses the list directly from the backend.

Comment: Yeah he can access the list its not possible from both the sides either you give him read only permission or contribute permissions. If you give him contrubute permissions he can do that CRUD operations please go through,  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Permission-levels-and-permissions-49d456eb-d3c8-4402-86b1-deb911224afb.                                       https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Understanding-permission-levels-87ecbb0e-6550-491a-8826-c075e4859848

Comment: My colleague think its not a good practice to allow direct access from the backend and wants me to implement the same functionality that the list provides by default through an interface. Im really confused right now.